# Using sendEmail with second alias from getAliases()

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-for-education

I have several aliases associated with my Google Apps for Education account at work.  getAliases gets them all, which is nice, but when I try to send an email from them using sendEmail, it only seems to work with the first alias, which is my personal one.  If I try it using any alias other than [0], nothing happens, and I don't get an error.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and was racking my brain, only to realise I'd been using MailApp and not GmailApp.

This may not solve everyone's problem, but it's just to add to a checklist of possible mistakes someone may have made.

Answer (score 0):

This is the example from [`getAliases()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getAliases%28%29). WFM.

```
// Log the aliases for this Gmail account and send an email as the first one.
var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
Logger.log(aliases);
if (aliases.length > 0) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(me, 'From an alias', 'A message from an alias!', {'from': aliases[0]});
} else {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(me, 'No aliases found', 'You have no aliases.');
}
```